# Ubuntu Replicate Files on Remote Servers

Tags: ubuntu, file-transfer

I have server 1 and Server 2.

In step one there is one script running in server1 that generates one file, after the process of creating the file is finish I need to upload the file to Server 2.

What is the best method and approach?

Thanks,
Pedro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to transfer files in linux. The most common and simples way is scp:

```
scp [[username@]host:]file-to-copy [[username@]host:]target
```

[]- marks optional arguments. If you for example is login in to server 1 you could do:

```
scp file-to-copy server2:/location/to/put/the/file/in
```

or if you need a different username on server2, change server2 to username@server2

If you which to have some more advanced features, like syncing and only copying new files, take a look at rsync (checkout man rsync)

Comment: Assumes sshd (package openssh-server) running on the target machine.

Comment: Ah, yes. Thank you, forgot that it is not installed per default in ubuntu.

Comment: Don't forget keypairs without passwords allow you to copy without prompts etc. Making it easy to script.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys
https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/serverguide/C/openssh-server.html

Answer (score 1):

[rsync](http://www.samba.org/rsync/) is a good way of doing this